# dplyr custom lag function for irregular time series

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr

I have an irregular time series, where there are gaps in the dataset. Further, the data is grouped. The lag functions I have been able to find lag by observation (so they find the prior record in the dataset), but I want to specify a time variable and have the lag calculated by matching the lagged time. This question: [R lag/lead irregular time series data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753810/r-lag-lead-irregular-time-series-data) is doing a similar thing. However, I can't use `zoo` solution (I have some sort of package incompatibility and can't use `zoo` at all) and have been unsuccessful in making the `data.table` solution into something sufficiently flexible to use as a function with lag amount as an input and the capacity for grouped data.

Test data:

```
testdf <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 counter = c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,11,12),
                 xval = seq(100, 1000, 100))
lagamount <- 1
```

The output should be the vector: NA 100 200 NA 400 NA 600 700 NA 900

This is what I am using at the moment:

```
library(dplyr)
testout <- group_by(testdf, group) %>%
  mutate(testout = function(x) which((testdf$counter - x) == lagamount))
```

This gives me a datatype error that something (unspecified) is not a vector.

Is there a way to make this construction work? Alternatively, how could I lag with irregular time series with grouped variables?

Comment: Perhaps you can call the relevant `zoo` function as `zoo::needed_function()` and avoid loading the package.

Comment: Also you're getting that error because you are supplying a function to `mutate`, and it expects a vector.

Comment: thanks I should have been clearer - zoo won't install on my machine, there is a problem with the Rccp dependency. Thanks for the error message interpretation, i will have another attempt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this within `dplyr`, whithout resorting to using `do`, would be to first make implicit missing values explicit, and filter them out afterwards.

Supply a vector to mutate, and use `ifelse` (or perhaps the new `dplyr::if_else`) to check whether the lag is what you want it to be. Example:

```
library(tidyr)
lagamount <- 2

testout <- group_by(testdf, group) %>%
  complete(group, counter = min(counter):max(counter)) %>% 
  mutate(testout = if_else(counter - lag(counter, lagamount) == lagamount, 
                           lag(xval, lagamount), 
                           NA_real_)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(xval))
```

Produces:

```
Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
Groups: group [2]

   group counter  xval testout
   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1      1       1   100      NA
2      1       2   200      NA
3      1       3   300     100
4      1       5   400     300
5      1       6   500      NA
6      2       7   600      NA
7      2       8   700      NA
8      2       9   800     600
9      2      11   900     800
10     2      12  1000      NA
```

Comment: thank you. unfortunately, that only works with a single time unit lag. It can't, for example, retrieve the value that is 2 or 3 time units previous (unless that coincidentally is the previous observation). This is why I was trying to work with `which`.

Comment: Ok, the edit should solve that, I think. Otherwise, could you give the expected output for `lagamount = 2`?

Comment: sorry, about the delay, was out of internet range. Output definitely looks like what I want. Yes, filingl in the missing data points and then deleting them at the end is a good approach. Will work my way through and accept in a couple of minutes. thank you, I would never have been able to produce this myself.

Comment: Glad I could help. Sorry it took me a few iterations to understand what was going wrong.

Comment: Isn't that code redundant? If you `complete()` the dataset, you will always end up with `counter - dplyr::lag(counter, lagamount) == lagamount`, no (at least after sorting by counter)?

Answer (score 1):

An efficient solution to this is now available in `collapse::flag` (and also `fdiff` and `fgrowth`). When creating the data you need to make sure the time variable is integer, otherwise it will internally be converted to factor which in this case removes the irregularity.

```
testdf <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                     counter = as.integer(c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,11,12)),
                     xval = seq(100, 1000, 100))
lagamount <- 1
```

Then we can write:

```r
library(collapse)
settransform(testdf, L_xval = flag(xval, lagamount, group, counter))
testdf
#>    group counter xval L_xval
#> 1      1       1  100     NA
#> 2      1       2  200    100
#> 3      1       3  300    200
#> 4      1       5  400     NA
#> 5      1       6  500    400
#> 6      2       7  600     NA
#> 7      2       8  700    600
#> 8      2       9  800    700
#> 9      2      11  900     NA
#> 10     2      12 1000    900
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You also have the option to generate a sequence of lags and leads (or specific lag/lead orders), either using pipes:

```r
testdf |> gby(group) |> flag(-1:3, counter)
#>    group counter F1.xval xval L1.xval L2.xval L3.xval
#> 1      1       1     200  100      NA      NA      NA
#> 2      1       2     300  200     100      NA      NA
#> 3      1       3      NA  300     200     100      NA
#> 4      1       5     500  400      NA     300     200
#> 5      1       6      NA  500     400      NA     300
#> 6      2       7     700  600      NA      NA      NA
#> 7      2       8     800  700     600      NA      NA
#> 8      2       9      NA  800     700     600      NA
#> 9      2      11    1000  900      NA     800     700
#> 10     2      12      NA 1000     900      NA     800
#> 
#> Grouped by:  group  [2 | 5 (0)]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Or doing in-place modification with `settransformv`:

```r
settransformv(testdf, "xval", flag, -1:3, group, counter, apply = FALSE)
testdf
#>    group counter xval F1.xval L1.xval L2.xval L3.xval
#> 1      1       1  100     200      NA      NA      NA
#> 2      1       2  200     300     100      NA      NA
#> 3      1       3  300      NA     200     100      NA
#> 4      1       5  400     500      NA     300     200
#> 5      1       6  500      NA     400      NA     300
#> 6      2       7  600     700      NA      NA      NA
#> 7      2       8  700     800     600      NA      NA
#> 8      2       9  800      NA     700     600      NA
#> 9      2      11  900    1000      NA     800     700
#> 10     2      12 1000      NA     900      NA     800
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

`fdiff` and `fgrowth` work similarly and also support iterations and compunding. You can also apply these functions to irregular time series (without a panel-id), then you need to specify `t = counter`. All functions can be applied to vectors / time series, matrices / xts, data frames / data tables / tibbles, and also support plm panel-series and data frames if you are looking for an object oriented approach.

More information at: https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/reference/time-series-panel-series.html

Comment: just a quick question, why do you use apply = FALSE here? apply = TRUE,should give the same solution? Can you elaborate a bit what exactly is the difference between apply = TRUE and apply = FALSE

Comment: @Vitalijs the difference is that `apply = TRUE` applies the function to the whole subset of the frame. If we have more than 1 variable to lag this is more efficient, because using `flag.data.frame` means we only need to group/index the data once and can apply the lagging across columns in C++, instead of using `lapply` with `flag.default` and re-indexing each time.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to make the expansion explicit and removed the strict datatyping in the if_else when I turned the above answer into a function. This is the final form.

```
getlag <- function(timevar, valuevar, laglength){
  df1 <- data.frame(counter = timevar, value = valuevar, indf = 1)
  alltimes <- data.frame(counter = seq(min(timevar), max(timevar)))
  df2 <- merge(alltimes, df1, all.x = TRUE)
  df2 <- df2 %>%
    mutate(lagvals = ifelse(counter - lag(counter, laglength) == laglength,
                            lag(value, laglength),
                            NA_real_)) %>%
    filter(!is.na(indf))
  return(df2$lagvals)
  }
```

And the test use case is:

```
testout <- group_by(testdf, group) %>%
  mutate(testout = getlag(counter, xval, 1))
```