# Calculate lagged variable in unbalanced time series data.table

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

How to create a lag variable in unbalanced time series table (unevenly spaced in time) ?
From data table -

```
ts = data.table(time=c(10,15,22,25,28),value=c(7,2,14,22,11), key="time")
```

How do you create lagged variable `value_lagged` of `value` by `time-5` ?

```
time value value_lagged
10 7 NA
15 2 7
22 14 2
25 22 2
28 11 14
```

My usual solution is to create a huge cross-join table and then use 'by' + 'min' to get back to initial state, but this doesn't work for 1M tables.

This question has an answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36754846/1317325 but too hard to find.

Comment: Just post that comment by referencing to the one who posted it as an answer there. Or if you want to post as Q/A style then include more details than what you have in the body of the question. Not just a link.

Comment: I have been stumbling upon this problem for 3 years now, each time spending an hour or so to figure out fastest solution
As Arun't comment no so easy to find, it's better be here

Comment: Agreed. But still, don't you think your "question" does not reflect the problem so clearly. Just make it a reproducible example, with more details. Again, don't post just a link. That makes your question to be lost in SO after some time. Unless you want to document it only for yourself.

Comment: I knew I'd end up spending more time for edits :) Anyway, thanks for forcing me, now it's much more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is copypaste from Arun's comment from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36754846/1317325)

```
ts[, value_lagged := ts[.(time=time-5), value, roll=+Inf, rollends=TRUE, mult="first", on="time"]]
```

For LEAD you can just change the signs -

```
ts[, value_lead := ts[.(time=time+5), value, roll=-Inf, rollends=TRUE, mult="first", on="time"]]
```

Comment: So you are saying this is actually just a duplicate?